# How to combine 4 different dat files in java

Tags: java, file-io, collections

Ok so I have 4 different files in java that are in .dat but they are all in text. I'm wondering which collection is best to use and how will I combine them together

Here are the 4 .dat files

The scores.dat consists of PERSONA_ID|GAME_ID|WIN

The personas.dat consists of ID|PLAYER_ID|GAMERTAG|PLATFORM

The players.dat consists of ID|FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME|EMAIL|BIRTHDATE

The games.dat consist of ID|NAME|PRODUCER

Here are some other information that might be useful

scores.dat PersonaID = Persona.dat ID

scores.dat GameID = Games.dat ID

Comment: What do you want the result to be? "Combine" is pretty vague.

Comment: You can create 4 pojo class consists of getter and setters (DTO) for scores, personas, players and games to store attribute values and keep these DTOs in 4 separate ArrayList. After that I am not sure how you want to "combine" them.

Answer (score 0):

You can read each file and append the contents of the files to a single String and then write the combined String out to a new file. You can use StringBuilder for better performance if you are going to add many files in this way.

You don't need any data structure if you only want to append the contents of files. If you have any other requirement for 'merging' the files, you will need to use appropriate data structures.